# killing httpd spawns new processes

Tags: macos, mac, activity-monitor

In short, I need to kill all httpd processes so I can run a particular program. When I go to Activity Monitor and Quit all of the httpd processes, a new one is immediately spawned. I'm not sure what is causing this, and would like to know how to effectively kill httpd without it launching again. I'm guessing something else is requiring it and thus the automatic spawning, so maybe you can help me determine where that's coming from.

I'm running 10.8.2, and trying to run Tiny Umbrella to store my SHSH blobs so I can downgrade my dev phone after upgrading to iOS 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This daemon doesn't start by default on OS X, so the stop procedure depends a bit on how yours is configured to start. Have you tried issuing `apachectl stop` to see if that is sufficient to unload the launchd job?

You can read up on the default starting and stopping of httpd via the apachectl tool on the manual pages (locally or [online](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/apachectl.8.html)) .

Comment: thanks for the clarification. apachectl stop did the trick